# Making my divs continue on one line, instad of adding new row

Tags: html, css

EDITED QUESTION!

Any idea how i can make my col-3 continue on 1 scrollable line, without making a new row. As for now, my code is adding a new row.

[image: Issue image]

But what i'm trying to make it do, is that when i'm adding a new div box, instad of it pushing the other divs on a new row, it's gets a overflow and continue to be on one line that is scrollable.

```css
.bettingTips {
  width: 30em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bettingTipsBox {
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px #a9afba;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid p-0 bettingTips">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-3 bettingTipsBox">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 MatchVS">
          <b>VS</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <b>Spil Forslag</b>
        <i>Complexity sejr 2-0</i>
        <hr>
        <b>Begrundelse</b>
        <i>Vi tror de vinder fordi de har store nosser</i>
        <br>
        <b>Spilles på</b>
        <img src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bettingTipsBox">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 MatchVS">
          <b>VS</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <b>Spil Forslag</b>
        <i>Complexity sejr 2-0</i>
        <hr>
        <b>Begrundelse</b>
        <i>Vi tror de vinder fordi de har store nosser</i>
        <br>
        <b>Spilles på</b>
        <img src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bettingTipsBox">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 MatchVS">
          <b>VS</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <b>Spil Forslag</b>
        <i>Complexity sejr 2-0</i>
        <hr>
        <b>Begrundelse</b>
        <i>Vi tror de vinder fordi de har store nosser</i>
        <br>
        <b>Spilles på</b>
        <img src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bettingTipsBox">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 MatchVS">
          <b>VS</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <b>Spil Forslag</b>
        <i>Complexity sejr 2-0</i>
        <hr>
        <b>Begrundelse</b>
        <i>Vi tror de vinder fordi de har store nosser</i>
        <br>
        <b>Spilles på</b>
        <img src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bettingTipsBox">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 MatchVS">
          <b>VS</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <img class="MatchImg" src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <b>Spil Forslag</b>
        <i>Complexity sejr 2-0</i>
        <hr>
        <b>Begrundelse</b>
        <i>Vi tror de vinder fordi de har store nosser</i>
        <br>
        <b>Spilles på</b>
        <img src="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
I've made a codepen to display my error:
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/UnScope1337/pen/yLZQXZm)

Answer (score 2):

You have not written the HTML code in the correct way. You have placed some extra **divs** which makes the code behave incorrectly. Here is the formatted code.

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row g-0 bettingTips">
      <div class="bettingTipsBox">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-5">
              <img src ="assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
              <b>VS</b>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
              <img src = "assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
              <b>Spil Forslag</b>
              <i>Complexity sejr 2-0</i>
              <hr>
              <b>Begrundelse</b>
              <i>Vi tror de vinder fordi de har store nosser</i>
              <br>
              <b>Spilles på</b>
              <img src = "assets/logo/Complexity.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To make the content scrollable is possible by setting height to the **bettingTips** class and making the **bettingTipsBox** class to take the full height. Here is an example of the CSS code that must be applied.

```
.bettingTips {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bettingTipsBox {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 30px !important;
  width: 25% !important;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your divs horizontally scrollable,

Set the container to `display: flex;` and Apply `overflow-x: auto;`.

Ensure each child div has a fixed width so they collectively exceed the container's width.

```css
.bettingTips {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.bettingTipsBox {
    width: 25%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answere. I've tried doing that, but i still seems to make it into a new row. [link](https://prnt.sc/K2BhlJzpdOHU)Image